# YSLOW ETag and Expired headers errors in ASP.NET MVC Website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, etag, yslow

When I validate an ASP.NET MVC web site with YSlow I get 2 errors:

1. Grade F on Configure entity tags (ETags)

   There are 7 components with misconfigured ETags

   The components are static images on a folder.
2. Grade F on Add Expires headers

   There are 9 static components without a far-future expiration date.

   The components are also static images.

Why do I get these errors? How can I solve this?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure IIS to send cache headers. In IIS manager, select a site / application, then you can open the `HTTP Response Headers` feature and then on the right bar click on `Set Common Headers` then check `Expire Web Content`.

Now, I've always put static content on a separate domain, so I'm not sure what happens if you service from your asp.net application, so you can play around with it, but that's where the configuration is in IIS.